Movie in which some teenagers (or two) were able to time travel by inserting a chip into their wrist
I can't remember the name of the movie in which some teenagers (or two) were able to time travel by inserting a chip into their wrist.
One teenager tightens his tie and gives an unimpressed gesture of himself.
While in custody, one teenager makes fun of an officer by saying, "Is he muscular or is he just fat?" and laughs.
In the end scene, there was a baby, and the teenager with him can see their reflection in the mirror, meaning they are not in the original universe as he thought.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you watch this?

This is Everywhen (2013).

Everywhen is when everything happens at the same time. In the year of
2077 a large count of the worlds population, 3 billion, suddenly
disappears. Did they all go to a parallel reality? A 17 year old boy
forces himself back from this reality, to try to save his 6 year old
brother.




It includes the line:

Do you see that guy over there? Is that muscles, or is he just fat?

